# What is the etiquette for modifying posts?

Tags: support, faq, edits, etiquette

I'm getting pretty close to the reputation where I can start to edit others' posts, and I'm wondering what the etiquette for when (and when not) to do so.

I figure that I should edit in the following circumstances:

- Grammatical or spelling errors.
- Clarification where the meaning is not changed. For instance if the title does not describe the question very well.
- Where the user has made a very minor mistake that doesn't justify a full post to clarify.
- To add related resources or links that will help someone answer the post, or provide context

Before the commenting feature was added, I **noticed that some moderators edit posts in order to insert a reply or extension to the post. I feel this isn't good etiquette** (but I could be wrong) because I don't know what to do with their changes when I come to re-edit or respond.

I also feel that I should **be very careful not to change the meaning of any question or answer**, even if that meaning is misguided.

What other rules would be best practice?

- Signatures and fluff are discouraged and are fair game to be removed.  See, for example, this post by [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468303/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed-on-stackoverflow/468725#468725) and this post by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468303/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed-on-stackoverflow/468332#468332) and also see [What is the policy on signatures and links in answers for SO questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277128/what-is-the-policy-on-signatures-and-links-in-answers-for-so-questions-closed).  Also see Jeff Atwood's response in the comments to [The Great Edit Wars](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/#comment-15830)

[Return to FAQ Index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq)

Comment: Jeff posted some more guidance on the Stack Overflow blog: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/

Comment: Related: *"[When should I make edits to code?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200336)"*

Answer (score 104, accepted):

> I've noticed that some moderators edit posts in order to insert a reply or extension to the post. I feel this isn't good etiquette (but I could be wrong) because I don't know what to do with their changes when I come to re-edit or respond.

You've provided a great list that matches well with my expectations of our community. You **edit to make things better, clearer, more effective -- never to change meaning**.

Of course all this has to be codified in the FAQ.

Comment: How ironic that the accepted answer to this question is one that was edited and then rolled back.

Comment: Yes it is ironic. The editing rules should also apply to answers as well as questions.

Comment: Yeah, Patrick and I disagreed slightly, he's more editorial whereas I preferred to let the original stand. In this case he edited out references to a practice that was common during the closed beta, but much rarer (and less relevant) now. I felt that too many answers' context was lost by the change.

Comment: If users really want to modify the FAQ to change its meaning significantly, from a very clear 'never' to a very loose 'rule of thumb', they can go discuss these changes first. Until then, *never* edit posts to change their meaning.

Answer (score 69):

I think the types of edits that are acceptable can be summed up as [copy editing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-editing).

> The “Five Cs” summarize the copy
>   editor's job: make the copy (i) clear,
>   (ii) correct, (iii) concise, (iv)
>   comprehensible, and (v) consistent;
>   that is: make it say what it means,
>   and mean what it says. Typically, via
>   the publisher's house style, copy
>   editing ensures the use of correct
>   spelling, consistently used
>   terminology, accurate punctuation,
>   correct infelicities of style, i.e.
>   grammatical and semantic errors, and
>   formatting of text in accordance with
>   the house style headers, footers,
>   headlines, etc.

Comment: Good point, but I'd be careful in this environment. It would be quite acceptable for a sub-editor on a coding magazine to change all { } blocks to be on new-lines if that were the house style, I don't think we should be doing that sort of thing.

Comment: I was focused more on the 5 Cs. We don't have a house style. If anything try to honor the style of the original writer. That, and I'll delete "hi" / "thanks" because Jeff said to do so, /if/ I'm already editing for another, better reason.

Answer (score 28):

The first thing I want to say is that I am no longer inline editing posts. I wanted a way to respond to people's questions directly, and there is currently no built-in way to do this (though Jeff mentioned that "annotations" are coming soon).

In a way I was following [Jeff's example](http://beta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6532/is-editing-other-peoples-posts-wrong). But I think now there is consensus that this isn't a good practice, so thanks, Keith, for setting me straight.

Now to jump in with my thoughts, edit to:

- Fix grammar / fix spelling / improve formatting.
- Make the post clearer or more effective.
- Linking to other resources related to the post.
- Add a warning if the post is dangerous (i.e. recommends solution with a security vulnerability)
- Add new relevant information missing from the post.

But do not:

- Change the meaning of the post.
- Add inline conversation.

I want to point out that Jeff has [explicitly told us](http://beta.stackoverflow.com/faq) that Stack Overflow is going to be wiki-like and is not a discussion forum. Those with edit ability who have something important to add shouldn't feel bad about doing so—it's the whole point of the site.

Comment: Yep - I definitely think formatting changes should be allowed. Someone edited my Code Golf (12 days of christmas) post to put a CR before the code! I never knew that.

Comment: @Lucas Jones: Code Golf seems to have different editing rules than normal questions so that longer solutions can be replaced by shorter ones.  Perhaps there should be a question about etiquette for modifying code golf posts, but I have a feeling it'll be closed into oblivion.

Comment: Both of the links in this answer are dead and I can't figure out where they should go (assuming the content still exists), otherwise I would **EDIT** the post.