# etiquette of translating comments in a post

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

Here's an issue that isn't addressed by [What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694630/translate-a-for-to-assembler) is well written and nicely formatted.  It includes some code too.  The comments for the code are written in Spanish.

I imagine that most people on SO don't read Spanish.  Is it a breach of etiquette to edit the post and translate the comments into English?

Comment: Do you want to change Spanish variable names also?

Comment: depends on how meaningful they are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A large slice of the SO pie is English speaking, so it would be a valid edit to translate that code sample into the main language of the site.

If you want it both ways, include the translation beneath or above the original language:

```
 push ebp
     // Guardo el estado actual de esp
     // Save the current state of esp*

*Translated from Spanish to English based on Google Translate
```

Couldn't hurt to help them get more eyeballs who might not know the language.

If you went with [Babelfish:](http://babelfish.yahoo.com/translate_txt)

> I keep the present state from ESP

Comment: Good idea, but it will enlarge the code block.

Comment: Then again, he could translate the whole thing and have the original still just sitting in the edit history preserved.