# Why is askubuntu.com not ubuntu.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Joel Spolsky just tweeted, "the official ubuntu q&a is live on stack exchange!"  However, it's not "on stack exchange".  It's at [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/).  Weren't we [just informed](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/) that all the sites are going to be sub domains of stackexchange.com?  Why the exception for this site?

Comment: All sites are equal, but some sites are more equal than others.

Comment: I agree, it would save domain money :P Everyone please donate to the stack-exchange they are buying domains with there own money.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

SE had an agreement with Canonical with regards to SE possibly replacing the current Ubuntu forums. As explained on Ubuntu MSE:

> Due to Stack Exchange's prior agreement with Canonical Ltd., ubuntu.stackexchange.com will recieve your askubuntu.com domain name, as orginaly agreed.

Source: [What should our com domain name be?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1/what-should-our-com-domain-name-be)

Comment: Was that before or after the vote to merge with Unix?

Answer (score 2):

In exceptional cases like this, where

1. We have a an agreement in place with an existing outside community
2. The outside community's goals (Ubuntu, Inc.) are aligned with ours (Stack Overflow Internet Services Inc.) -- namely "make the internet better"
3. The domain name is quite good (there is the possibility of redirecting from ask.ubuntu.com if this agreement works out)

Then custom domain names are possible.

Comment: -1: Who decides what is a good domain name, and what isn't?

Comment: The domain name is quite good?  Seriously?  I mean, it's not *bad*, but it's hardly creative genius.  It looks a little capricious to hold that up as an example of a "good" name after declaring so many other names to be "monstrously bad."

Comment: Well askubuntu is good, its obviously a place where you ask about ubuntu, simple. Unlike NothingToInstall which has no connection to asking, and [no pun intended] has nothing to do with installing.