# How to seek experienced StackOverflow users' opinions?

Tags: discussion, meta

Is there an acceptable place to ask experienced StackOverflow users their opinions about things like copy editing?

For example, I have a particular question about editing a post - however, I'm not looking to duplicate a question which has already been asked here: [What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts)

I'm looking for a *specific* opinion, and meta is clearly not the place for that.

So where is?

Comment: I'm loving the downvote with no reason given.

Comment: On Meta, downvotes just mean disagreement. :) (No, it wasn't mine, in case you were wondering.)

Comment: Uh yeah... You already found that place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Opinions are very important on Meta, more so than on Stack Overflow.

If you express an opinion about the way you believe Copy Editing should be done, I'm sure you'll get Answers which make it clear if people agree or not.

And if you happen to duplicate a post, then it will be closed ... but shouldn't that happen? We don't need duplication.

Oh, I just noticed the downvote. *That's the way you find out if other users disagree with you.*

Comment: OK... Thanks. I'll ask a new question as an opinion question.

Comment: On the other hand, Steve, accepting an answer *too quickly* reduces the incentive for others to answer. *Feel free to change the acceptance if something better comes along*.

Comment: I'm making some assumptions about my relative level of experience with Meta :) ... If you ask a bunch of runners how to crawl, the chance you'll get a bad answer is pretty small - so the risk of accepting an answer too soon because there are a number of competing opinions also seems pretty small in this case.