# How to get initial reputation on Stack Overflow with the new-user restrictions in place?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, new-users, privileges

I understand that reputation can be gained by answering questions. However, it seems that more often than not the questions do not contain all the required information to give an answer. Since new users can not comment questions and ask for more details, this creates a sort of *catch-22*.

Any good advice on how to get initial reputation, given the new user restrictions?

Comment: Now, would you believe that I have Catch-22 at arm's length?

Comment: Just answer some easy question. Save the hard ones for next week. 50 rep is like 2 or 3 answers, no big deal.

Comment: I have not had any success just by browsing questions. If a question is simple and answerable, it is already taken by 'the fastest gun in the west'. The rest lack details.

Comment: Would the top specific tactic be:
"Ask some good new questions and nicely manage/curate the answers you receive?"

(as that, and this comment, have been the only things I can do so far)

Comment: You can gain reputation by editing posts in StackOverflow. This video helped me for the first time: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Owpn0SCzkLU

Comment: Get an accepted answer. +15!

Answer (score 44):

50 reputation isn't all that hard to get, unless you're only knowledgeable in a very specific and isolated section of programming. Sure, that initial 50 reputation might seem like an insurmountable barrier, but it'll be gone before you know it if you do the following things:

- **Write well-formed questions and answers** — Do your research. If a question doesn't seem to provide enough information, you don't have to write a very specific answer. Research what could possibly cause the error and post as many solutions as you can. If your technical knowledge is lacking right now, post [good questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question).
- **Improve Stack Overflow** — Propose edits for answers and questions. Even if it's just grammatical or orthographical errors, correcting such things will improve the readability and provide better accessibility to other SO users/visitors.
- **PROGRAM** — Above all else, *keep programming*. It's easy to get into a rut just surfing Stack Overflow. Don't do this. You'll learn more programming by doing, which will expand your knowledge base for answering questions, and you'll eventually run into problems while programming, which will provide fuel for questions.

Remember, when asking or answering questions, [no question is too basic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers) (unless it's a duplicate). Stack Overflow is to be *the* repository of programming knowledge, essentially the [Library of Alexandria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_of_alexandria) without all the fire and burning.

Comment: Thanks for convincing me to stop absent-mindedly flipping through meta and get back to work...

Comment: Don't worry, you'll be back in ten minutes. I know I will...

Comment: +1 for "without all the fire and burning" Oh and the rest of the answer was also good, I suppose :P

Comment: Trivial edits are the way to go: https://github.com/cirosantilli/stack-overflow-vote-fraud-script/blob/master/puppets.md#bootstrapping

Answer (score 16):

Advice based on recent experience.

**Recap**

Initially it is very hard to find questions you can answer for rep and you can't ask clarification without comment rights.

**Recommendations**

- **Do not browse at random**. The volume of questions on Stack Overflow is huge. If you just hit refresh you are probably just wasting time.
- 'Very easy questions' are probably not a very good investment either. They are quickly taken by the 'fastest gun in the west'.
- **Setup some filtering**. Browse a bit and look for tags. There are likely some tags with a lot of volume that are not relevant to you, **ignore those**. Similarly adding favorites may actually let you find something relevant.
- **Keep programming**. Keep developing code and searching for solutions. This is a good way to find relevant questions. Questions related to specific libraries are more likely to be complete and answerable than very general questions on some programming language.

Answer (score 1):

**I just ask questions!**

I rarely answer questions, rate things, or edit things, yet I have 5k of reputation on Stack Overflow.

Primarily I use Stack Overflow as my problem unblocker.

If I get stuck on something, I try to write up the question in the clearest possible language so the problem is easily understood. Usually within an hour I have a good answer for common things, or a few days if I am working with something really obscure.

**Sometimes Stack Overflow is just my duck**

While writing up the problem, since it has to be clear, I will often [rubber duck debug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) myself into the answer, and I will either answer my own question or just delete the question if it doesn't seem like it would be useful to others.

With this method, SO becomes my tool, and the points are a side effect. What is nice is that when you ask questions, you will continue to get points forever as people find and upvote the question.

Comment: Why don't you search on Stack Overflow for similar questions (not a rhetorical question)? Is it too hard to find them (finding the right keywords, way too many false positives, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

#### Suggest Edits

[Reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) is earned only by posting *questions* and *answers* or by *suggesting edits* to existing Q&A.

When you post Q&A, you'll only gain reputation when other users upvote it. Your post may stay at 0 for a long time if no one sees it or finds it useful.

If you're looking to quickly gain some rep to post a comment, the more pragmatic approach is likely to [suggest edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts) to existing posts whenever you see something that can be improved. These edits should move relatively quickly through the review queue, and each good suggested edit will earn you **+2** reputation.

---

With only a few hours or days worth of suggested edits, you will gain all of the useful low-reputation [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

- 5 Suggested Edits: Remove new user restrictions
- 7 Suggested Edits: Vote Up
- 25 Suggested Edits: Comment Everywhere
- 62 Suggested Edits: Vote Down
- 100 Suggested Edits: [Association Bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work), so you'll never have to do this again on other SE sites.