# Strategy for reputation

Tags: discussion, tags, reputation, up-votes

I was wondering if anyone is interested in sharing their strategies for gaining reputation.

Here are some specifics:

Assuming one has a few favorite tags, should he focus on one, or all?

Should one avoid answering any specific questions?

Is there a certain style of writing that increases the chances of upvotes (if yes is there an article on this)?

Comment: Generally, legible English and proper grammar/spelling will increase your chances of upvotes. Posting things in all lowercase (or uppercase), leaving out verbs, or using shortened forms of words will not. But that's not really a strategy, more common sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get over 200 reputation points every day?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8086/how-to-get-over-200-reputation-points-every-day)

Comment: Related and possible duplicate: [Six simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/) ◊ [What is the best way to increase my reputation and privileges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146472/) ◊ [How to get over 200 reputation points every day?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8086/) ◊ [How to get initial reputation on Stack Overflow with the new-user restrictions in place?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139661/) ◊ [What's the best way to boost my Stack Overflow score?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50148/) ◊ And many others.

Comment: Go to the Users tab to see a list of users ranked by recent reputation.  Find someone who isn't currently banned, figure out where their rep came from and copy that strategy.  It's a form of flattery.

Answer (score 8):

> Should one avoid answering any specific questions?

Well, starting to answer questions which are bound to get closed is *generally* a bad idea as you can end up typing a good answer which you then can't post - although if you think you can get an answer in quickly *and* you think the question won't actually be deleted, that means it's more likely to end up being accepted (you get less competition). I don't actually think about things like that when answering, but in hindsight it makes some sense.

Fundamentally, just try to be helpful. The more helpful you are, the more votes you're likely to receive. By the time you hit the rep cap regularly you *could* start trying to optimize for accepted answers instead of votes, but it's not really a good idea. If you're doing it for the reputation rather than to be helpful, you're missing the point anyway.

A while ago I wrote a blog post on [answering technical questions helpfully](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) which you may find useful - but it's aimed to helping, not at reputation.

Comment: "starting to answer questions which are bound to get closed is generally a bad idea" - pretty ironic, considering this very question got closed quickly.. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Indeed...

Answer (score 5):

Go through the list of bounty questions (featured tab) and do your best to answer the questions there - interact with the posters, get more details from them and give as complete an answer as possible.

These will gain you both upvotes for good answers and reward you with bounties.

One [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/517815/mrgomez) who did this gained reputation extremely fast.