# Is importing data from comment into answer OK?

Tags: discussion, comments, edits, specific-question

I'm asking about this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3242364/2389310

One [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242282/how-to-configure-an-existing-git-repo-to-be-shared-by-a-unix-group/3242364#comment3349057_3242364) provided important missing data, and [answer's author agreed on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242282/how-to-configure-an-existing-git-repo-to-be-shared-by-a-unix-group/3242364#comment3349064_3242364). But he didn't edit it into an answer. Comments are meant to be ephemeral and short-lived, and [this answer in FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11486/225745) (no downvotes) lead me to believe it is OK to edit information into the post. Why not, if post's author confirmed it should be there?

So I [suggested it and got it accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3811527), and then in mere minutes it was [rolled back](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3242364/revisions).

I don't want to start an edit war, so I ask here - was it a good edit or not? And was this rollback justified?

Comment: As the author agreed, I think that edit was fine. It's better to have the pertinent information in an answer. You can then flag the comments as obsolete (or use a custom reason and explain what you've done).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I can't flag this comment as I upvoted it. If you could be so kind to take care of it? Or let's leave them be, no harm in it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a lot wrong and bad edits which are (in my opinion) accepted. Your edit looked like a a comment, thus I rollbacked it after seeing it was quickly accepted. After reading it again I realized I was wrong and your edit is perfectly right to me now. I rollbacked again to your edit.

Sorry for the inconvenience. I will definitely check better my review next time!

Comment: No problem. I spend most time on Drupal Answers where there is a lot less traffic and calmer moderation, I was ready to accept that rules on main SO may be a bit different. Glad we have it figured out without a war - that's what I like Stack for.

Answer (score 3):

(IMHO) It is fine to edit an answer and add data from comment. And it is absolutely fine to do it when the answer's author agreed on it but didn't edit it. We also do the same with questions when the OP adds his code (what has he tried) later in comments.

If someone rolls back your edit, instead of rollback war you should politely ask him the reason for roll back as [I did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242282/how-to-configure-an-existing-git-repo-to-be-shared-by-a-unix-group/3242364#comment31805401_3242364) in the particular answer. By this either one of you will be convinced.