# Is there a FAQ that can be accessed from the Android mobile app?

Tags: support, android-app, meta-faq

I was recently referred to [What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts) where Jeff refers to creating an FAQ.

Does it exist, and is it accessible from an Android smartphone's Stack Exchange app?

Answer (score 3):

It's just an [ordinary question with links to answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) so yes you can access it from the app.

If you searched for FAQ it would be the first question that appeared.