# Would adding more examples to a post be acceptable?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

For example, in [this question](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/8510/12937), the OP lists two examples of the model. I know another one, and think that it doesn't change the meaning of it. But as it's also out of the author's awareness/intention, would it be fine to add it?

From *[What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11476/260800)*:

> You edit to make things better, clearer, more effective -- never to change meaning.

Comment: Hi @PeterMortensen, what does "active reading" mean in your edit reason?

Comment: He probably applied [this technique](http://www2.open.ac.uk/students/skillsforstudy/active-reading.php) and didn't find anything else wrong in your post after he applied all his editing rules. In general he hardly ever replies to comments.

Answer (score 2):

I actually suspect adding a comment might work there.

Alternately - if it fits the "core" of the question better

> Is there one or more models of human states of mind or emotions that as of 2014 is most accepted or best regarded by the fields of cogsci/psychology/psychiatry?

You might be able to post it as an answer *if* it could be seen as such.

That said, the question feels potentially opinion based.

Comment: I forget to say, the example is another graphic, so it's better to put it in the . What do you think?

Comment: I'd say in this situation, editing the question is a terrible idea. Popping in a link to the graphic in a suitable comment for the question might work. Thoooough, its an odd question - would asking  a new question, referencing this one, asking  for what's considered the best in 2018 be on topic/not be a duplicate?

Comment: why do you think it's bad? I think the OP would add it too if he knew it. Just linking it on the comment will significantly reduce the visibility of the image, and there needs not to say more beside the image.

Comment: as for reasking, why would your 2018 version be less opinion based than this one? And if there is a new candidate, we can simply just answer on that question anyway

Comment: IDK, maybe close that one too ;)