# What is the difference between "only applicable to one specific site" and "a general question stems from a specific example"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, meta, per-site-meta, example-questions

The reason I ask [Would adding more examples to a post be acceptable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315511/260800) in the mother meta instead of the child meta is because I think it's applicable to other sites as well. So what is the difference between "only applicable to one specific site" and "a general question stems from a specific example"?

Comment: The close voters here are trigger happy when you provide an single example post from a specific site. It sits in the [re-open queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/59753) so let's if those re-open reviewers are any good ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That close reason has been changed [fairly recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308227/im-changing-the-not-generally-applicable-close-reason-here-on-meta-se), precisely to avoid questions like these from being closed. I've voted to reopen as well.

I can imagine cases where a specific question/example is *so* specific to a single site that it's better / compulsory to ask it on the site's own child meta, but this question is definitely not one of them.

Comment: this answer satisfies my innermost question, but not the titular question. I'm not sure if I should accept it or not.

Comment: It's hard to answer the question in the title, it will vary on a case by case basis (and which reviewers you encounter). I think Shog's post was meant for us to judge a bit more often for the "general question" (i.e. Leave Open) option.