# What can I do if I want to ask a more specific version of an earlier question on a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

To provide context, on the Law Stack Exchange, I'd like to be more specific than the question here:

*[Are cheater plugs illegal in the USA?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/71263/are-cheater-plugs-illegal-in-the-usa)*

I'd like to know specifically if it's illegal to use currently-owned cheater plugs in a household under Florida and Ohio's jurisdictions. However, since the question above is similar to that, what should I do?

1. Should I edit the question accordingly?
2. Should I start a new question?

I don't want to lose points and so wanted to determine the correct course of action first. Would one of the two options above be good, or is a third option the best?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11476/282094)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would ask the more specific question and include a link the more general question with an explanation of why that doesn't answer your question. For example:

> I read
> [Are cheater plugs illegal in the USA?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/71263/are-cheater-plugs-illegal-in-the-usa) and the answer said that this is handled on a state-by-state basis. I would like to know the legality specifically in Ohio and Florida.

I would also include any attempt I made to figure out the answer for myself, and details about how I want to use those cheater plugs, for example if I am a landlord installing them for a renter, or a renter using them in my apartment, or a homeowner using them for myself.

Comment: (Also, you would probably have been better off asking on [law.meta.se], where the community could give you more specific advice on how they like that particular situation handled)

Comment: Actually, I didn't even know there was a Law Meta, haha. This is my first Meta post on Stack Exchange, so I guess I'm learning.

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Should I edit the question accordingly?

No, that would change the meaning of the post (even if you would add it as a sub-question). That's not the job of a [copy editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11478/295232) - that FAQ also made it to the [Help Center]

> 2. Should I start a new question?

That seems to be the best option in most circumstances. It even made it into one of the standard comments for answers-that-are-not-an-answer in the Low Quality Posts review queue:

> #### This is a different question posted as an answer
>
> If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Make sure that readers understand that your question isn't answered by the original question (you don't have to specify so explicitly if it's clear enough) in order to avoid having it closed as a duplicate.

A third option, if an answer almost applies in your situation but not entirely, you could ask the author in a comment if they could update their answer to include your specific question. That could become a mess though (imagine if users from all US states would do so, for one or two states at a time ...)