# "How to Edit" information in edit page is meaningless to OP

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits

I am a user without the [edit privilege](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/edit) in Ask Ubuntu.

When I click the edit button on [my own post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1265991), this is shown:

[image: Screenshot of edit page]

The *How to Edit* information is kinda meaningless to the OP.

> How to Edit
>
> - Correct minor typos or mistakes
> - Clarify meaning without changing it
> - Add related resources or links
> - **Always respect the author’s intent**
> - **Don’t use edits to reply to the author**

The last two points are weird as I am the author of the post.

Please consider changing these points to something better or remove them.

---

If you are user with the edit privilege, this issue can be noticed when you right click on the edit button and open the link in a new tab/window.

[image]

---

I agree with [Rob](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/282094/rob)'s [suggestion in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1248891). The last two points can be changed to these:

> "Use edits to address or clarify points made in comments and **possibly** answers" and "Remember to not alter the question significantly if it would invalidate existing answers".

Comment: I guess you missed the last point of my post. I am the author of the post. So the sentence "*respect the author’s intent*" is weird as I am the author.

Comment: Oh, well that makes all the difference. I guess that the powers that b want you to respect your own intent, and not talk to yourself.. Odd, I agree.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. What do you mean by "*powers that b*"?

Comment: Do you have a link to the post? That side bar dialogue doesn't show if I'm editing my own post.

Comment: @bad_coder https://askubuntu.com/q/1265991 Is the sidebar dialogue shown to me because of the fact that I have less than 2k rep in Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: "the powers that be" is an idiom meaning the people who decide these things - SE wrote the code in this case, so them.

Comment: Meh. It doesn't really hurt anyone to have those points there. Often, people don't even see these yellow things due to banner blindness. If they do notice them, it's probably one of their 'first times' editing anything. Wouldn't want people missing out on things just because the first post they edit a couple of times is their own. Also, what 'better' thing should these points be changed to then, instead of leaving them out entirely when you're editing your own post?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I am not really sure about what the last two points can be changed to. I guess removing the last two points if it's one's own post is fine.

Comment: Random, the last two points: 1. "Always respect the author’s intent" and 2. "Don’t use edits to reply to the author" would be more applicable to the OP if they were reversed and reworded: "Use edits to address or clarify points made in comments and **possibly** answers" and "Remember to not alter the question significantly if it would invalidate existing answers". --- That suggestion could do with some refinement, but something along those lines. --- Related but not duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11474/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/282094

Comment: *[powers that be](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/powers_that_be#Noun)* - *"1. (idiomatic) The holders of power or the authorities in a given situation, especially if seen as being faceless or unreasonably bureaucratic."*