# Is it appropriate for another person to edit a question to link to informational resources that could have prevented the need for the question?

Tags: discussion, edits, hyperlinks

I'm browsing through questions with extremely high scores on stackoverflow.com to find one-liner questions that I think show a lack of research effort. In the process, so far I have found two questions where a user who didn't ask the the question edited the question to add links to informational resources that could probably have prevented the need for the asker to ask the question in the first place.

- [What is the difference between __str__ and __repr__?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1436703/11107541)

  - revision #9 added links to Python official documentation
- [What is RESTful programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/671118/11107541)

  - revision #9 added a link to the Wikipedia article on the topic of the question

Note: These are just motivating examples. They're from stackoverflow.com, but I think the scenario can be generalized to other Stack Exchange sites. Let's put aside the question of whether you think the examples reflect a lack of research or what your personal judgement is on the quality of those posts if it would get in the way of answering this question. For the rest of the question, let's say we're looking at an edit to a question which adds a link to an information resource from a well known and reputable source (let's also put aside whether you think Wikipedia is a reputable source), and we agree that the author of the question could have found that resource if they spent a reasonable/small amount of research effort, and we assume that the author did not do that research and therefore did not find that resource.

If the author had seen and used those resources, they should/would have linked to them themselves and indicated what specifically they had difficulty understanding from those resources. So I consider it safe to assume that if the link wasn't there in the first place, the author hasn't seen that resource or even a link to that resource.

The "How to Edit" dialog for suggesting edits states (among other things):

> 2. Clarify meaning without changing it
> 3. Add related resources or links
> 4. Always respect the author’s intent

**#2** doesn't seem to me to be relevant here (although I'm not certain). **#3** in isolation would support such an edit, but **#4** could possibly (with a *little bit* of what could be accused of being mental acrobatics) be understood to disapprove of such an edit. The author's intent in such a one-liner indicating lack of research is *based on* their lack of research. If a person edits such a question in a way that isn't reflective of the lack of research which motivated the question, couldn't that be said to be to be indirectly disrespecting the author's intent?

Note: As [answered by @Robert Longson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382826/997587), both the examples I linked were asked a *long* time ago when standards for quality were different and those informational resources may not have existed at the quality they have now or may not have existed at all. I'm not asking just about that scenario. I'd also like to know for questions that are asked recently.

If you would like to share you personal subjective thoughts on the good-ness of such edits, feel free to do that as well with an appropriate notice statement.

Related:

- [How do I make a good edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219/11107541)
- [Is it OK to edit the question to change the author's intention?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288802/11107541)
- [What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11474/997587)

Answer (score 8):

Those questions are both 13 years old. Times change, sites are generally somewhat less strict in their youth than later on in life as early on each question is going to be unique and useful, later on those same questions will simply be frequently asked duplicates.

Do you know that the linked documentation did exist as usefully as it does now 13 years ago? The revisions that added the links in were made this year. Perhaps that research was done 13 years ago and the documentation was lacking at that time. Maybe the presence of these questions spurred the documentation writers to write that documentation or if not, at least to make it clearer.

Having the links in the question does not change the meaning of the question and it certainly does make it easier to find that documentation so what's the harm? We should make questions as useful as possible. All those upvotes on the questions themselves do suggest that they themselves are useful and that people want to read their answers.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks! I would also like to have an answer for hypothetical questions which are asked recently. I wasn't clear about that in my original question. I have edited to be clear about that.

Answer (score 1):

In the Python example (the same could be said of the RESTful post), adding a pinpoint to the official documentation potentially saves the readers a few clicks and keystrokes if they also want to check the docs. (Not to mention inexperienced users who may not even be aware the docs/API exists or how to search in it.)

Besides, official docs have a narrower scope than an SO thread and are frequently written for conciseness, often posts on SE will expand with context, examples and perspectives so it makes perfect sense to have both together. Notice, however, that's it's a common practice to avoid [repeating/duplicating links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Linking#Duplicate_and_repeat_links) so having the links at the very top of the thread is the optimal place to put them.